# Tiered pricing for configurable products in Orocommerce

Tags: orocommerce

I am trying to add tiered pricing for configurable products in Orocommerce.

Example: I want to market t-shirts in different colors with tiered pricing e.g. 10 USD/each but if you order 5 or more (regardless of color or combination thereof), you get them for 9 USD/each.

The issue I am running in to, is that I have only managed to get the tiered pricing to work for the simple product variants e.g. if you order 5 red t-shirts, but not if you order 3 black and 2 red t-shirts.

If I add pricing to the configurable product (and not the simple variants) the pricing does not show up on the store front.

Is there a way to create a configurable product with tiered pricing based on the combined quantity of the variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prices are intended to be managed only [on a simple variants level](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/product-management/#simple-vs-configurable-products). If there are prices defined in a configurable product, out of the box, they are used only for informational purpose.

> Is there a way to create a configurable product with tiered pricing based on the combined quantity of the variants?

Not out of the box. As configurable products are just visual wrappers by default. Prices and quantities are managed only on a variant level.

You can achieve something similar with [promotions functionality](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/marketing/promotions/promotions/). It affects only prices in the order review and the shopping list pages, but not on the product view page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. 

As a follow-up question. How would I go about getting a sum of the collection in the promotion e.g. a "sum quantity if product sku = x" ?

I've found the lineItems.sum() in the documentation but I am unsure how to filter the collection before summing?